# How to change origin of a 3d transform?

Tags: css, css-transforms

I'm applying rotateX transform to an elment and would like to move the origin of that transform to the top of an element. Using transform-origin property doesn't seem to work..

```
transform-origin: 50% 0% 50%;
```

check the fiddle please.
http://jsfiddle.net/y977K/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `transform-origin:top`, which is equivalent to `transform-origin:0% 50%;` and `transform-origin:top center`. [**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/y977K/3/)

For a full chart of the possible values a `transform-origin` as well as what each keyword equivalency is, check out [**mozilla's developer page on it**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)